# SFML vector of custom class containg sf::Font segmentation fault

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

EDIT HAS BEEN MADE. IT'S AT THE BOTTOM.

I have a class, `game::graphics::Button`, which has a member of type `game::graphics::Label` and a few more things, and the `Label` contains `sf::String`, `sf::Text` and `sf::Font`.

When I instantiate `Button` (and therefore `Label` with it) it works fine, it deallocates just fine, but when I try to push it to a `vector`, it causes the font to have `0xcdcdcdcd` values (allocated, uninitialized) but when I don't push it to the `vector`, it works fine.

I think this is caused by one of the copy constructors or move constructors of `Label`, but I don't know why and how to fix it.

The code for better understanding:

```
class Label final : public sf::Drawable{
    sf::String str;
    sf::Text text;
    sf::Font font;
public:
    Label() {}

    // More constructors here

    Label(const Label& lhs) : str(lhs.str), text(lhs.text), font(lhs.font)
    //when the code comes to here, it causes segmentation fault, because font contains 0xcdcdcdcd
    {
        text.setFont(font);
    }

    //some other code
};
```

`Button`'s code(only showing the one called):

```
Button(float xPos, float yPos, float xSize, float ySize,
       const std::string& imagePath, const Label& _label = Label(),
       bool intialVisible = true)
    : label(_label)
    , z(0)
    , active(intialVisible)
{
    sf::Vector2f position(xPos, yPos);
    sf::Vector2f size(xSize, ySize);

    if (!texture.loadFromFile(imagePath))
        std::cout << "not loaded\n";

    int32 autoCorrectPos = -5;
    buttonImage.setTexture(texture);
    buttonImage.setPosition(position);

    buttonImage.setOrigin(buttonImage.getGlobalBounds().width/2, buttonImage.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
    graphics::scale(buttonImage, size.x, size.y);
    auto& Pos = buttonImage.getPosition();
    label.setOrigin(label.getGlobalBounds().width/2, label.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
    label.setPosition(Pos.x, Pos.y + autoCorrectPos);
    ButtonManager.push(this);
}
```

It even finishes running when I step through code but it causes segmentation fault inside `vector`.

The code that is run when it fails:

```
std::vector <game::graphics::Button> playerAttacks;

playerAttacks.push_back(game::graphics::Button(400, 150, 80, 80, "pictures/itachi.jpg")); //this line fails already
playerAttacks.push_back(game::graphics::Button(400, 260, 80, 80, "pictures/itachi.jpg"));
playerAttacks.push_back(game::graphics::Button(400, 370, 80, 80, "pictures/itachi.jpg"));
playerAttacks.push_back(game::graphics::Button(400, 480, 80, 80, "pictures/itachi.jpg"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

So it seems that the code that was crushing it was:

```
//copy construct
Button(const Button& b) : texture(b.texture), 
                          buttonImage(b.buttonImage),
                          callBack(b.callBack),
                          hover(b.hover), label(b.label),
                          active(b.active)
{
     buttonImage.setTexture(texture);
     ButtonManager.push(this);
}
```

or possibly(didn't check which one is called, most likely this one):

```
Button(Button&& b) : texture(std::move(b.texture)),
                     label(std::move(label)),
                     buttonImage(std::move(b.buttonImage)),
                     callBack(std::move(b.callBack)),
                     hover(std::move(b.hover)),
                     active(std::move(b.active))
{
    buttonImage.setTexture(texture);
    ButtonManager.push(this);
}
```

I changed them to not manipulate the variables on the initializer list, but instead assign(in move constructor move assign) the variables in the body.

It is solved, but I am very curious as to why this is the way it is. That assigning them works, but constructing them didn't.